# RxJava Android: Observer incompatible types error

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java, rx-android

I have the following Async network call I'd like to make by using RxJava and RxAndroid. I included the latest `RxJava` (3.0.1) and `RxAndroid` (3.0.0) in the project dependencies, but still get the following error in the `Subscription subscription = ....` block:

> Incompatible types
>
> Required: org.reactivestreams.Subscription
>
> Found: void

Why is that? Can anyone tell me how to make this RxJava observable work?

Any help apprechiated, thanks.

```
Subscription subscription = getServerResponse(et_id.getText().toString())// error highlighted in this whole block
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(new Observer<String>() { 
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String bitmap) {
               // Handle result of network request
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
               // Update user interface to handle error
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
               // Update user interface if needed
            }
       });

public Observable<String> getServerResponse(String string) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            BufferedReader inFromServer = null;
            String response = "";
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, serverPort);
                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                outToServer.writeBytes(string + "\n");
                response = inFromServer.readLine();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.result_serverError);
            }
            return response;
        }
    });
}
```

All my imports for reactive java:

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observer;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
```

Comment: Check your imports, maybe you are using the wrong observable.

Comment: I use `import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;`. Isn't this ok?

Comment: Did this ever work for you? Did you migrate from 1.x? Please read [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscriber) section.

Answer (score 0):

try using a composite disposable. It would be something like this:

```
private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable();
compositeDisposable.add(getServerResponse(et_id.getText().toString())
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(new Observer<String>() { 
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String bitmap) {
           // Handle result of network request
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
           // Update user interface to handle error
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
           // Update user interface if needed
        }
   }));
```

Dont forget to do a compositeDisposable.dispose() on the onDestroy method of your activity.

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: No this doesn't work, Seems like I miss some dependency to use this. Isn't this from RxJava2? I use `v3`. It wants to rename `onSubscribe` to `MainActivity` and all sorts of other stuff. All I want to have basically is an async call to the server via a socket and update the UI using an observable.

Comment: Well, managed to resolve the issue. I chose to use a `Disposeable`, which  resolved the issue. Thanks anyway :-)